# How to counter a written offer when there was no question about pricing?

Tags: pay-rate, negotiation, price-per-hour

Just got off call with prospective client. He's one that a friend has worked for before and can vouch for. We talked for about a half-hour and it led to him saying he'd send me a contract with details tomorrow (so basically an offer).

It's mostly for making small updates to his iOS apps. He said he's flexible to when I work and for how many hours I put in.

It's all hourly and not fixed-cost. He did not ask for an hourly rate though. I imagine this is his way of letting freelancers not be able to negotiate. From what my friend said before, it's generally low-pay.

What do you think? I feel like even if I'm content with the rate that I should always try to negotiate.

Comment: Are you able to send an email recapping the conversation and include your rate to this prospect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I lucked out in that I was going to same town where client lived in. He said he'd be down to meet for coffee just to say hi.

Having the face-to-face interaction really helped break the awkwardness of asking what the rate was and I didn't need to elongate the anxiety of waiting to see the contract the day later and then negotiate.

So he told me rate and I was able to negotiate there on the spot.

Meeting clients in-person may not always be practical. So I'd say to set up a video-chat to discuss things. Worst-case scenario is a voice-call, but I learned anything textual just complicates things.

Comment: It should not be up to the customer to set a rate. When someone asks me a rebate, I can accept, but he'll never know that the yield lowers.